# How to start with Kiwi API?

Tags: kiwi-tcms

I would need some help with Kiwi API since I can't find any instructions for how to start and what to use from scratch except "pip install tcms-api". My plan is to have automated test which will report Test Case status (Failed or Passed) via Kiwi API. Also, I would like to use all methods for exporting/importing Test Plans etc.

Do you guys have any documentation on how to get started with the API?

I am running docker on windows machine and have started Kiwi via docker-compose.

Is there any difference running API client on Windows or Linux?
Do I need to configure something on server side in order to access API?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> My plan is to have automated test which will report Test Case status (Failed or Passed) via Kiwi API.

which automated test framework is this ? Doesn't any of the plugins or standard format parsers listed here work for you: 
https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins.html

> Do you guys have any documentation on how to get started with the API?

Standard documentation points to both client-side and server-side documentation:
https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/index.html

Doesn't this help you ? If no, what is missing ?

> Is there any difference running API client on Windows or Linux?

No

> Do I need to configure something on server side in order to access API?

No